# Visual Studio Form Resize Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-10

I created a WinForm with splitcontainer. In Design-Time form resizing works perfectly. However when I start the app, controls of the right panel are not visible/way bigger then expected. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this scenario when I use a Windows 10 computer, What we do is to update the computer, then the sizes of the controls becomes as expected.